# The given validation code was rejected by the PVF pre-checking vote

Tags: parachain, collator

I'm running a local relay for testing, which is all working great. The issue comes in when joining a parachain to the network - I can get as far as submitting an upload for the genesis state and WASM. It sits for a minute, goes through an epoch or two, but then I get an event called "PvfCheckRejected".

Reading through some issues on the Polkadot repository, I can find that this seems to occur when 2/3 validators are unable to process the uploaded WASM in a reasonable amount of time, but the runtime used to upload fine and other than an upgrade to polkadot-v0.9.43 we haven't changed anything. I've rebuilt the chain spec a few times and regenerated the WASM and genesis state, but we're still getting the same response. I doubt it's a problem with the relay chain spec, since the relay's validators are working perfectly, and I did just double-check to make sure the validation code matches the validation code found in the chain spec.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm overlooking.

Our chain spec is https://github.com/fennelLabs/Fennel-Protocol/blob/terraform/plain-parachain-chainspec.json

If it's helpful, the WASM for the runtime on that chain is located next to the chain spec at https://github.com/fennelLabs/Fennel-Protocol/blob/terraform/para-1000-wasm

Bootnode runner script:https://github.com/fennelLabs/Fennel-Protocol/blob/terraform/boot.sh

Bootnode log with `-ldebug`: https://app.warp.dev/block/xQm8E0wWaMRIzXcVjff18V

Main collator runner script: https://github.com/fennelLabs/Fennel-Protocol/blob/terraform/collator-1.sh

Main collator log with `-ldebug`:
https://app.warp.dev/block/cPt2XzChSTVfrEuN2QlJst

The parachain does onboard successfully (but doesn't begin collating, but that's a different problem) if I use the dev accounts (Alice, Bob, Charlie) for the validators and collators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer posted at https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5747/4330, I was able to determine that *I was missing private keys that should have been inserted.*

Following the documentation, I knew I needed to insert the `babe` and `gran` keys, but missed the other 5 keys (`imon`, `para`, `asgn`, `audi`, `beef`) listed in that table. They were already in my chain spec, but needed to be specifically inserted by name. Once I inserted them, it works perfectly.

From what I can tell, the PVF check runs before validation code is committed from a new parachain, and needs the `para` key inserted on every validator so they can sign their votes to accept or reject the parachain. That explains why validation worked perfectly but other pallets didn't.

Comment: This isn't a clear answer to this question. Do you mean insert the keys on a relaychain validator or parachain collator? Since nobody except those running the relaychain can update the relaychain validators it would be impossible to solve a production problem this way. Also Alice and Bob local (rococo) relaychain should not require this.